# An algebra problem: Let $a+b+c=0$. Prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2 =6/5$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a,b,c$ be nonzero real numbers such that $a+b+c=0$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3 = a^5 +b^5 +c^5$.  Prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2 =6/5$

I tried to expand $(a+b+c)^5$ but I can't get term of $a^2+b^2+c^2$.

Comment: Use the ideas given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182260/quickest-way-to-find-a5b5c5-given-that-abc-1-a2b2c2-2-and-a).

Comment: @sailormars2016 I've just noticed that you haven't accepted any of the questions you've made on MSE, although some of the answers were really good. I'm not saying that you *have to* accept answers, but it is sometimes nice - for those who answer - to know that their answer was helpful (since it was marked as *accepted*). Please take this into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: With $$c=-a-b$$ we get in $$a^3+b^3+c^3-a^5-b^5-c^5=0$$ the equation
$$ab(a+b)(5a^2+5ab+5b^2-3)=0$$

Answer (score 3):

When you see symmetric equations, try the following substitution $$a+b+c=s=0\qquad ab+bc+ac=q\qquad abc=p$$ And rewrite the equations in terms of $s,q,p$

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)\implies a^3+b^3+c^3=3p$$

$$a^5+b^5+c^5\stackrel{(*)}=-5(ab+bc+ac)(abc)=-5qp$$

(*) means: in this case.

If you're wondering how I obtained this, use [Newton's Identities](https://brilliant.org/wiki/newtons-identities/). It isn't hard, but long.

Finally $$a^3+b^3+c^3=a^5+b^5+c^5\implies -5qp=3p\implies q=-\frac35$$ Now $$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ac)=s^2-2q=\frac65$$

Comment: Searching on the internet, I've just noticed, that the identity $$\frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{q}=-5p$$ under the condition $s=0$, has a proof [here](https://www.quora.com/If-a+b+c-0-then-a-5+b-5+c-5-ab+bc+ca)